Django populating a form on a modal
I have a problem with populating a form on a modal pop up. I can get a form added to the modal, but I want it to be based on the line a user clicks on.
My view:
class SalesQuotationDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
template_name = 'Sales/quotation_details.html'
def get(self, request, quoteid):
    quotation = Quotation.objects.get(id=quoteid)
    quotationlines = QuotationLine.objects.filter(quotation=quotation, deleted=False)
    company = quotation.customer
    quotationform = QuotationForm(initial=model_to_dict(quotation), companyid=company.id)
    newquotationlineform = NewQuotationLineForm()
    context = {
    'quotation':quotation, 
    'quotationform':quotationform,
    'quotationlines':quotationlines, 
    'new_quotation_line':newquotationlineform,
    'table_title':"Quotation Lines", 
    'table_heading_1':"Article", 
    'table_heading_2':"Amount", 
    'table_heading_3':"Price per Piece", 
    'table_heading_4':"Lead Time", 
    'table_heading_5':"Line total"
    }
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)

def post(self, request, quoteid):
    quotation = Quotation.objects.get(id=quoteid)
    quotationlines = QuotationLine.objects.filter(quotation=quotation, deleted=False)
    company = quotation.customer
    quotationform = QuotationForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=quotation, companyid=company.id)
    if quotationform.has_changed and quotationform.is_valid():
        qform = quotationform.save(commit=False)
        qform.updated_by = request.user
        qform.updated_date = timezone.now()
        quotationform.save()
        messages.success(request, f'{quotation.number} has been saved correctly')
        return redirect('sales-quote-details', quoteid=quotation.id)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, f'{quotationform.errors}')
    newquotationlineform = NewQuotationLineForm(data=request.POST)
    if newquotationlineform.has_changed and newquotationlineform.is_valid():
        newquotationline = newquotationlineform.save(commit=False)
        newquotationline.quotation = quotation
        newquotationline.total_line_price = newquotationline.amount * newquotationline.price
        newquotationline = newquotationlineform.save()
        messages.success(request, f'The new quotation line was added succesfully')
        return redirect('sales-quote-details', quoteid=quotation.id)
    context = {
    'quotation':quotation, 
    'quotationform':quotationform,
    'quotationlines':quotationlines, 
    'new_quotation_line':newquotationlineform,
    'table_title':"Quotation Lines", 
    'table_heading_1':"Article", 
    'table_heading_2':"Amount", 
    'table_heading_3':"Price per Piece", 
    'table_heading_4':"Lead Time", 
    'table_heading_5':"Line total"
    }
    return redirect('sales-quotations')

And my template:
    {% extends "start/parent.html" %}
{% block body %}
            <!-- Content -->

<form id="formAuthentication" class="mb-3" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
                            <div class="row">
                              <h4>Quotation information</h4>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-6 order-0">
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.number.label }} {{ quotationform.number}} </h6>
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.entity.label }} {{ quotationform.entity }}</h6>
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.customer.label }} {{ quotationform.customer }}</h6>
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.contactperson.label }} {{ quotationform.contactperson }}</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-6 order-0">
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.invoice_address.label }} {{ quotationform.invoice_address }}</h6>
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.delivery_address.label }} {{ quotationform.delivery_address }}</h6>
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.deliveryterms.label }} {{ quotationform.deliveryterms }}</h6>
                              <h6>{{ quotationform.project.label }} {{ quotationform.project }}</h6>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-6 order-0">
                              <h6> {{ quotationform.valid_date.label }} {{ quotationform.valid_date }} </h6>
                            </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-6 mb-6 order-0">
                                <h6>{{ quotationform.attachments.label }} {{ quotationform.attachments }}</h6>
                            </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick='history.back()'>
                                Close
                              </button>
                              <a href="{% url 'delete' tecobject='quotation' tecobjectid=quotation.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>
                            </div>
</div>     
</form>                   
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4 order-0">
<table>
  <caption>{{ table_title }}</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>{{ table_heading_1}}</th>
    <th>{{ table_heading_2}}</th>
    <th>{{ table_heading_3}}</th>
    <th>{{ table_heading_4}}</th>
    <th>{{ table_heading_5}}</th>
    <th>              <div class="col-sm-6 text-center text-sm-left">
                                   <!-- Extra Large Modal -->
                      <div class="modal fade" id="exLargeModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel4">Create a new Quotation Line</h5>
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                class="btn-close"
                                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close"
                              ></button>
                            </div>
                      <form id="formAuthentication" class="mb-3" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                {{ new_quotation_line.as_p }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                                Close
                              </button>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                      </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <div class="card-body pb-0 px-0 px-md-4">
                  <!-- <img
                    src="../static/images/illustrations/man-with-laptop-light.png"
                    height="140"
                    alt="View Badge User"
                    data-app-dark-img="illustrations/man-with-laptop-dark.png"
                    data-app-light-img="illustrations/man-with-laptop-light.png"
                  /> -->
                </div> 
                <a
                          type="button"
                          data-bs-toggle="modal"
                          data-bs-target="#exLargeModal">
                          <img class='add-button' src="../../media/plus.png">
                        </a>
              </div>
            </th>
  </tr>
{% for quotationline in quotationlines %}
  <div class="col-sm-6 text-center text-sm-left">
                                   <!-- Extra Large Modal -->
                      <div class="modal fade" id="QuotationLineModal{{ quotationline.id }}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel4">Edit Quotation Line</h5>
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                class="btn-close"
                                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close"
                              ></button>
                            </div>
                      <form id="formAuthentication" class="mb-3" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                {{ edit_quotation_line.as_p }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                                Close
                              </button>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                      </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <div class="card-body pb-0 px-0 px-md-4">
                  <!-- <img
                    src="../static/images/illustrations/man-with-laptop-light.png"
                    height="140"
                    alt="View Badge User"
                    data-app-dark-img="illustrations/man-with-laptop-dark.png"
                    data-app-light-img="illustrations/man-with-laptop-light.png"
                  /> -->
                </div> 
              </div>
<tr>
  <td>                <a
                          type="button"
                          data-bs-toggle="modal"
                          data-bs-target="#QuotationLineModal{{ quotationline.id }}">
                          {{ quotationline.article }}
                        </a></td>
  <td><a
                          type="button"
                          data-bs-toggle="modal"
                          data-bs-target="#QuotationLineModal{{ quotationline.id }}">{{ quotationline.amount }}</a></td>
  <td><a
                          type="button"
                          data-bs-toggle="modal"
                          data-bs-target="#QuotationLineModal{{ quotationline.id }}">{{ quotationline.price }}</a></td>
  <td><a
                          type="button"
                          data-bs-toggle="modal"
                          data-bs-target="#QuotationLineModal{{ quotationline.id }}">{{ quotationline.lead_time}}</a></td>
  <td><a
                          type="button"
                          data-bs-toggle="modal"
                          data-bs-target="#QuotationLineModal{{ quotationline.id }}">{{ quotationline.total_line_price }}</a></td>
  <td><a href="{% url 'delete' tecobject='quotationline' tecobjectid=quotationline.id %}"><img class='delete-button' src="../../media/close.png"></a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
</div>  
</div>                  
{% endblock body %}

I don't know how I can sent the data from a quotationline to the edit_quotation_line form. Now it is an empty form when I declare that in my view. I would like to pass it to the form for each line.
I tried with an include, but that gave me the same problem. I could access the variables, but I couldn't get the form to populate with the data from the quotationlines.
I also tried to do an extend, but that didn't solve the issue either, since I don't sent the data to another page.
I have spent hours trying to solve this, but I don't know how, can someone help me?
